# Find the sub-set of unique objects in a list which contains duplicate references to the objects

Tags: python, list, object, unique

I have an algorithm that creates a set of lists in the values of a dictionary.  However, the number of lists is less than the number of dictionary keys because some of the values are references to the same list object.

When the algorithm is complete, I want to extract a list of only the remaining unique list objects. I want to avoid having to compare two lists since this is inefficient.

I came up with this way to do it using the [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function.  Maybe this is fine but I wasn't sure if this is an appropriate use of id and wondering if there's a simpler way to do it.

```python
# Start with a full set of unique lists
groups = {i: [i] for i in range(1, 6)}

# Algorithm joins some of the lists together which 
# reduces the total number
for a, b in [(1, 2), (2, 4)]:
    groups[a] += groups[b]
    groups[b] = groups[a]

print(groups)
```

Output:

```
{1: [1, 2, 4], 2: [1, 2, 4], 3: [3], 4: [1, 2, 4], 5: [5]}
```

Note: Now some of the values of the dictionary contain the same list, `[1, 2, 4]`.

```python
# Find the remaining unique lists
all_values = list(groups.values())
ids = [id(x) for x in all_values]
result = [all_values[ids.index(a)] for a in set(ids)]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 4], [3], [5]]
```

This is a common question in other languages but I couldn't find one on how to do this in Python.

Comment: Two lists that are equivalent (in terms of their content) do not necessarily share the same *id*

Comment: `id(obj)` is the way to go

Comment: @DarkKnight I think your point about the risk that two of the lists with identical values could potentially have different ids is valid.  So this method is not robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a dictionary where values (lists) may be duplicated.

Sets are useful for reducing duplicate data. However, as lists are not hashable you need to convert them to something else - e.g., a tuple

You could do this:

```
groups = {i: [i] for i in range(1, 6)}

# Algorithm joins some of the lists together which 
# reduces the total number
for a, b in [(1, 2), (2, 4)]:
    groups[a] += groups[b]
    groups[b] = groups[a]

print(groups)

result = list(map(list, {*(tuple(e) for e in groups.values())}))

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[3], [1, 2, 4], [5]]
```

A potential disadvantage of this technique is that the output order may not be what's required

**Note:**

Just to emphasise the *id* v. *hash* dilemma, consider this:

```
a=(1,2,3,4,5)           
b=(1,2,3,4,5)
                   
id(a)              
4429940832

id(b)           
4429952432

hash(a)           
-5659871693760987716

hash(b) 
-5659871693760987716
```

Comment: This works but does set use list comparison? For efficiency, I want to take advantage of the fact that I know many of the lists are the same object (as well as the same value).

Comment: @Bill The values in a set must be hashable - that's why this code converts the lists to tuples. It's the hash values that are compared. If performance is key then I suggest you try the code in this answer with a **much** larger dataset to see if it performs as required

Comment: Okay well tuple comparison is also potentially costly. Although in my case the lists happen to contain unique values so it will actually be efficient.  I’ll do some tests.

Comment: Use map to avoid list comprehensions. https://trinket.io/python/df28d50fe4

Comment: As pointed out above, tuple comparison isn't any more costly than any other object comparison; sets HASH their members and use the hash table to detect collisions

Comment: @MatBailie Edited. Is that better?

Comment: `set(map(tuple, groups.values()))` : https://trinket.io/python/e8b136130c

Comment: I ran your code with 1000 items in `groups` consisting of 10 unique lists of length 201 to 1000 and the wall time is 13.2 ms compared to 572 µs for the `set(ids)` code in my question.

Comment: However, as you pointed out above, what I was trying to do is not robust. There is a real risk that two or more of the lists may not share the same id even if their values are identical. So I think the additional computation cost of this solution is worth it.

Comment: @Bill There's really no point in having a piece of code that's faster than another when it may not produce the correct results. It is sometimes necessary to accept lower performance for greater accuracy

Comment: @DarkKnight I totally agree.